# Angular 2 CLI, Webpack in production

Tags: angular, webpack

I am working on an Angular2 application with large no of separate modules. I want to have separate bundle.js for each module instead of one.

I was able to do this before when separate config file for webpack was used but in new version of CLI there is no separate config file for webpack So how can I do it.

Comment: [This is a known issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187556/angular-cli-where-is-webpack-config-js-file)

Comment: ok thanx, I found the solution in github

Comment: @LAVKUMARVISHWAKARMA can you please share that solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your project with webpack directly without using angular-cli and use `require.ensure()` to include external file dynamically. 
Webpack will detect  `require.ensure` and will create a seperate chunk for it.