# Where is the webpack.config.js in angular-cli new project?

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I'm looking into webpack and also angular-cli, and even though angular-cli is supposed to use webpack, I can't see any `webpack.config.js` file when I create a new project with `ng new`

Does anybody know how does this work in angular-cli?

Comment: i think if you want to use webpack you need to use an angular-cli webpack plugin .. angular cli is not very mature at the moment

Comment: but as far as I know, angular-cli already uses webpack, that's what they say in the documentation

Comment: yesbut i think you need a plugin to manage it .. i think

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650744/role-of-webpack-in-angulars-ng-serve) helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656) thread about configuring webpack in angular-cli. It seems webpack is not configureable at the moment, but they are working on it.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`$ ng eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) to generate webpack.config.js in the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to edit webpack in angular-cli project.
There is a workaround repo. Hope this might help. [here](https://github.com/sharma02gaurav/es6-basecamp-ng2-weback). Or you can use a scaffolder too if you do it too often https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-scaffolder. Just choose the angular 2 webpack scaffold from the options.