# Role of Webpack in Angular's ng serve

Tags: angular, webpack

I am new to Angular and was wondering what role does Webpack play behind the scene when we ng serve the application. During initial impressions, I have come to know that webpack acts as a build and package tool that groups all the required JS files into separate bundles. I could not, however, find the webpack configuration file and could not figure how angular and webpack come together in the picture.

So when I serve the angular 4 app, this is what is printed on the terminal. Can't exactly understand what is happening behind the scenes.

```
webpack: Compiling...
Date: 2017-12-05T07:13:25.436Z
Hash: a6d360a858a29480ebbc
Time: 310ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 35.4 kB {vendor} [initial] [rendered]
kB {vendor} [initial] [rendered]                            ap (polyfills) 200 kB {inline} [initial]chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 200 kB {inline} [initial]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 195 kB {inline} [initial]chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 3.65 MB [initial]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Angular CLI effectively puts together a Webpack config file on the fly based on the project configuration options you pass in.

You can find the main piece of the code that generates this config [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/models/webpack-config.ts), and the code that passes it to Webpack when you run `ng serve` [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/tasks/serve.ts#L160).

Comment: Can you please elaborate the process a little so that it becomes clear as to how webpack is creating these packages. Also if possible any links where it is explained in detail in context to Angular. Thanks

Comment: @SalmanKazmi: There's not really much to elaborate on - the code that I linked generates a standard Webpack configuration (as documented [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)), and from that point on the build effectively works the same as any other Webpack build.

Comment: can you please update github links? links are broken,

Answer (score 1):

basically youre totally right!

maybe you want to have a look at the webpack article in the official documentation?
https://angular.io/guide/webpack

btw: webpack is used since late 2016 and has some benefits compared to Broccoli & SystemJS for example AoT and faster build times.

Comment: I read the detailed explanation provided in the link that you mentioned. The information although useful is again targeted towards explaining Webpack in general. I am looking for a resource that explains things in detail. Thanks though.

Comment: youre welcome, im new to that too, and just found this link and thought you might want to see it ;)