# TypeScript files stopped transpiling automatically into JavaScript in my Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

About a year ago, I created a project using the Angular Quickstart, which gives .ts files the ability to automatically get transpiled into .js files on Save.  A few months ago, this feature stopped working, and I'm not sure why.  I *think* it happened when Angular stopped using typings and instead started using @types.

Thankfully, the auto-reload feature still works for HTML and SCSS/CSS changes, so I know it's not totally broken.

All the files that I would like to be auto-transpiled have the extension .ts or .spec.ts, and are located in sub-folders of app/components or app/shared. For example, the foo component will be app/components/foo/foo.component.ts and the .spec.ts file for that component will be in that same folder.

Note: I am NOT using Angular CLI, and at this time converting the project to use Angular CLI is not in scope.

Here are the files that seem relevant - let me know if you need to see anything else:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" \"npm run generate-css\" \"npm run watch-css\" ",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "generate-css": "node-sass -r app --output ./generated-css",
    "watch-css": "node-sass -w -r app --output ./generated-css",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.2.4",
    "angular2-ui-switch": "1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "mydatepicker":"1.2.9",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io": "1.7.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "socket.io-client": "1.7.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "wijmo": "wijmo-system-min",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5",
    "typescript": "2.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.40",
    "@types/node": "6.0.58",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.39",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.62",
    "canonical-path":"0.0.2",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.25",
    "concurrently": "3.1.0",
    "http-server": "0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "live-server": "1.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "node-sass": "3.13.1",
    "nodemon": "1.11.0",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "tslint": "3.15.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "wijmo-system-min",
    "app/shared/date-picker"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE: Eventually I bit the bullet and switched the project over to Angular CLI... it took about a week to make the conversion, but at least now everything works again.  Therefore, even if someone answers this, I won't be able to verify if the fix is working or not.**

Comment: Where the files are located? in which folder? and with what extension?

Comment: @galvan all the files have the extension .ts or .spec.ts, and are located in sub-folders of app/components or app/shared.  For example, the foo component will be app/components/foo/foo.component.ts and the .spec.ts file for that component will be in that same folder.

Comment: Please try to add "compileOnSave": true, line before "compilerOptions": {...} in the tsconfig file

Comment: @David why do you need compile on save?

Comment: @galvan Unfortunately, it did not work.I would have been so happy if it were that simple!  I updated the question with that in the tsconfig.json to show how I added it.  I rebuilt after adding just to make sure.

Comment: @andrei-macarie so i don't need to type long commands every time I save a file... like tsc app/components/networking-table-dropdown/networking-table-dropdown.component.spec.ts

Comment: @David you can use [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create a new Angular project. Then migrate your files to the new project. Current implementation uses webpack which manages the whole compilation and bundling. Therefore no need to compile each file individually. If you want to manage the build process by yourself using webpack.config then you can do - [ng eject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187556/angular-cli-where-is-webpack-config-js-file-new-2017-feb-ng-eject) but this might add its own challenges.

Comment: @andrei-macarie I actually spent several hours trying to do just this.  Unfortunatey, this project was made so far before Angular CLI was available, it's entered a state that makes it extremely difficult to port over to use Angular CLI.  I would rather manually type tsc command rather than attempt this conversion process again.  That being said, if what I'm trying to do is no longer possible without using the CLI, that would be an acceptable answer.  Although I doubt that's the case, since the SCSS files still transpile to CSS.

Comment: @David what is so special about this project that cannot be easily ported? I mean, you have typescript, some dependencies, defined using import (I hope).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142108/discussion-between-david-and-andrei-macarie).