# Angular cli and webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

Having a play round with angular cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#documentation

I can create a simple app and view it at localhost.

If I inspect the localhost site I can see the css and js links inserted by webpack.

How are these added when the index.html looks like this

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Wpng</title>
      <base href="/">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Also I cant see any webpack.config.js in the files so how is webpack used

Answer (score 3):

The Angular CLI is handling the webpack.config file internally. If you want to see it and work with it manually, you can use the ng eject option.

See this answer for more information: [angular-cli where is webpack.config.js file - new 2017-Feb: ng eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187556/angular-cli-where-is-webpack-config-js-file-new-2017-feb-ng-eject)

Answer (score 3):

The `angular-cli` is made in a way that you should not be worrying about setting anything up in the `webpack.config.js` file as this is done already for you... Unfortunately, last time I checked there was no `official` list of all webpack `loaders` that are inclucded in the `angular-cli`, however, everything you think you'd need is already there. This is what makes `angular-cli` so simple and easy.

With that being said, the reason why you're not seeing any `javascript` files linked in the `index.html` file is because when you're developing, you're not actually working with a `build` but rather with an app that is kept in "memory" and changes as you develop your app. I know it's like magic and the first time I used `angluar-cli` I was confused about this too...

Lastly, if you actually `build` the project using the `ng build --prod` command, then you'll get a new directory called `dist` with the actual source code and a `index.html` file that links the `bundle.js` file as you would expect it.

As far as I know the `webpack config` is not supposed to be meant for changing in the `angular cli`. At least this was the case last time I checked.

Comment: How otherwise must we add 3rd party angular plugins to our project? Most plugins give a webpack option to add to the project.