# angular2 library official documentation

Tags: angular, typescript

What about official documentation for creating angular2 library?

I don't understand.
Why do we need to compile for creating library?

I'd like to have only source (some common modules) that could be reused in multiple projects without to have to compile it.

Comment: what build system do you use?

Comment: I'm using angular cli ( default, so webpack ).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to completely understand your problem, but as far as I know an Angular 2 library is nothing more but an Angular 2 application you import in another as a module using npm. For example [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core).

These kind of modules have to be added to your app.module.ts file.

Angular 2 accepts non-specific Angular 2 modules as well, and you can require them in your app. For example if you want to use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/), you can do :

```
npm i --save moment
```

And in your component or service or whatever:

```
import moment = require("moment");
```

So to create a library you can follow one of these schemes and nothing should run well.

If you use Webpack and want a library to be globally available (JQuery for example), you can require it in the vendor.ts file.

Comment: ngx-translate, has some line codes that i don't want to write :
example :  export * from "./src/translate.loader" in index.ts.

Is it mandatory ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are trying to say. Angular libraries should be AOT (ahead of time) compatible, meaning that when another project imports your library and they want to have their project AOT compiled, it will throw the error if your library (that they imported) is not ready for AOT compilation. There are a lot of requirements to fulfil for reusable angular library, and not a lot of documentation on it.

Comment: So, do you think, create a simple app (via ng new command of angular-cli), positionnate false to private in package.json) and publish it without to compile it will be importable in a another project ?

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you need to do.

The first thing is to create a *single* module that will be exported from your library and then can be imported into another application. This module can import or re-import other modules of your library.

Then, you need to create a declaration file with typings for your application. You can do that using `declaration: true` option of `tsc`. It can even be compiled into one file by using `outDir` option.

The last thing is that you should tell `webpack` not no bundle `@angular/...` dependencies into your bundle. This can be done using `externals` property. Read more [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx).

Comment: ok, but is the step "creation of declaration file" optional ? ( Isn'it used for angularJs only ? I know that my module will be used only in angular2 projects. it's a enterprise non public module deployed in private registry )

Comment: @JimmyPannier, no, it's not optional. If you create a class, for example, as a service, and other app will import it and call some method , the `tsc` will complain that it can't resolve that method on that class/service without declaration file

Comment: @JimmyPannier, please consider accepting the answer if it helped

Comment: do you know how to configure externals property using angular-cli ? I don't see such property in package.json or tsconfig

Comment: @JimmyPannier, you have to eject `webpack.config.js`, see [this](http://www.dzurico.com/angular-cli-with-the-super-powers/) for more information. I wouldn't say it's trivial and it has some [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42406194/2545680)