# Production compilation with ejected Angular 4 application produces large files

Tags: angular, production-environment, production, angular2-aot

`ng build --prod` Angular CLI command produces highly compressed javascript files in Angular4 application.

When the application is ejected using `ng eject` command, Angular CLI commands are gone and we are left with npm scripts( `npm run build` command to build the app), but unfortunately that command outputs a non-production build.

I tried running `webpack -p` command directly but the output result files are slightly *larger* compared to the output of `ng build --prod` command.

How to get a compression equivalent of `ng build --prod` command but on an ejected application? What command/arguments can produce such results?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can eject the production version of the webpack config by using the following command:

```
ng eject --prod
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use both the development & production versions of the ejected webpack config, do the following:

1. **Backup** your existing **package.json**
2. Execute `ng eject --prod` (this will eject the production version of webpack config)
3. **Rename** the **ejected** webpack.config.json to **webpack.config-prod.json**
4. **Restore** your backed up **package.json** (the actual changes are pretty much the scripts and few new packages). You might also want to edit your .angular-cli.json and change the `ejected` property to false.
5. Execute `ng eject` (this will eject the development version).

You're now left with a production & development version of your webpack configs. Now, to compile your Angular project for production, execute `webpack --config webpack.config-prod.js` and you can also add this to your package.json scripts for ease.

*However, this may not be the perfect method for this but this is what I did in the. If there's a better version, feel free to edit.*

Comment: the command worked. After ejecting I ran the build and minification was the way I neede it to be. But unfortunately I can't run the app in dev mode anymore. when I run `npm start` command, I get an error saying `webpack-dev-server is not recognized as an internal or external command`. So is there no way to use the ejected app in both modes (dev/prod) without cli? I'm looking for a solution to do it without any manual intervention, something out of the box solution of a kind.

Comment: What I ended up doing was generating a non-prod and a prod version  of the config using `ng eject` and `ng eject --prod` (_note that you need may have to reverse your package.json after the first eject_) and then using the production version of the webpack config while building for production like so: `webpack --config <prod-webpack-config>`.

Comment: That is a great solution! Thanks. Please update your original answer and include what you wrote in the comment, so that's easily readable by the viewers. Sometimes people miss the comments section.

Comment: Can I use those steps even if I already have ejected the webpack config file?