# How to work with ngcli after ejecting the webpack config?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I need to customise the webpack pack build in an Angular cli project. In order to configure I eject the webpack config file.

```
ng eject
```

Once I do that I can no longer run webpack build and serve command as I get the following error.

```
An ejected project cannot use the build command anymore
```

If the build commands can not be used after eject then what is the best way to work with webpack after eject.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187556/angular-cli-where-is-webpack-config-js-file-new-2017-feb-ng-eject/42406194#42406194

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular-cli where is webpack.config.js file - new angular6 does not support ng eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187556/angular-cli-where-is-webpack-config-js-file-new-angular6-does-not-support-ng-e)

Answer (score 4):

When you run the `ng eject` command this is the output that is displayed at the prompt:

```
ng eject
==========================================================================================
Ejection was successful.

To run your builds, you now need to do the following commands:
   - "npm run build" to build.
   - "npm run test" to run unit tests.
   - "npm start" to serve the app using webpack-dev-server.
   - "npm run e2e" to run protractor.

Running the equivalent CLI commands will result in an error.

==========================================================================================
Some packages were added. Please run "npm install".
```

Everything you need to know, right there.

Have a look inside the `package.json` to see the updates to the `scripts` section. There are a couple more commands there that are not shown in the output above.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

In case anyone was not aware, the CLI can still be used to generate code even after the eject has been done.

Commands like `ng generate component blah` will still work.