# How to build angular cli based project after switching to webpack using ng eject command

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Recently I switched to webpack from angular cli because I was facing issue with some libraries. I manually included few scripts within webpack.config.js file.  So, now how can I compile the angular project without switching back to cli?

Previously I used this command to compile the angular project: 
`ng build -prod --aot=false`

Is there any equivalent options within webpack?

Comment: See this:https://angular.io/guide/webpack#production-configuration

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861191/how-to-work-with-ngcli-after-ejecting-the-webpack-config/44861648#44861648

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to work with ngcli after ejecting the webpack config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861191/how-to-work-with-ngcli-after-ejecting-the-webpack-config)

Answer (score -1):

Why not use yarn

```
yarn build
```

Yarn is an alternative package manager for NPM packages with a focus on reliability and speed.

To enable Yarn for Angular CLI you have to run the following command:

```
ng set --global packageManager=yarn
```

More info can be find over [here](https://medium.com/@beeman/using-yarn-with-angular-cli-db2e318e43c5)

Comment: Thanks, how do I define `--base-href` path in yarn? since I'm not uploading project in the root directory so I'm getting 404 error for missing dependencies.

Comment: In your webpack.config.js, under module.exports look for "output" there you will find a path property which you can change as per you need.
ex:

"output": {
        "path": "/Users/jim/Desktop/dist",
        "filename": "[name].[chunkhash:20].bundle.js",
        "chunkFilename": "[id].[chunkhash:20].chunk.js"
    }