# Webpack 3.5.5 debugging in chrome developer tools shows two source files. One under webpack:// and other under webpack-internal://

Tags: google-chrome, express, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs, webpack-2

Migrated existing webpack project to use webpack 3.5.5 and its new config. Using express server instead of webpack-dev-server.
I had to setup the resolve in webpack as below.

```
const resolve = {
    extensions : ['.js'],
    modules : [
        'node_modules',
        'src',
        'testApplication'
    ]
};
```

When i debug this webpack application using chrome developer tools I can see the 2 versions of source files.

1. The first one under webpack://
    It is exactly matching with the source
2. The second one under webpack-internal://
    This one is the babel compiled version of the source.

My questions are

1. Is there someway where I get only a first version of the file instead of both?
2. I thought node_modules should have been implicitly defined as a module rather than me specifying it explicitly in resolve, is there someway that I can make the build work without having the node_modules defined in resolve.
3. After using the same source code with webpack 3.5.5(migrated it from webpack 1.14.0) the express server start seems to have slowed node. My guess is that having specified the node_modules in modules under resolve has caused it. Any ideas?

Comment: We might need to see your whole Webpack config. I don't have an answer off the top of my head though.

Comment: You could refer https://github.com/workco/marvin
I am using a similar config to it. When you start the webpack dev server and view source in developer options in chrome. You will find that you see the same file twice in it e.g. RouteStatus.jsx, once under webpack:// and second time under webpack-internal://.
The one under webpack:// shows the same file which is the source code whereas the second one shows a babel compiled i guess.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can configure the source maps using Webpack's `devtool` property. What you want is `devtool: 'source-map'`([source](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)). This will only show you the original source code under `webpack://`. Note that there are other options that might be more appropriate for your use case.
2. `["node_modules"]` is in the default value for `resolve.modules`. However, if you specify `resolve.modules` you need to include `"node_modules"` in the array. ([source](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules)). 
   It seems strange that you specify `"src"` and `"testApplication"` in `resolve.modules`. If you have local source files you should require them using relative paths e.g. `require("./local_module")`. This should work without having `src` in `resolve.modules`
3. Specifying `node_modules` in `resolve.modules` is not responsible for any slow down (see 2.). There are many possible reasons the slow down. E.g. maybe you are erroneously applying babel to the whole `node_modules` folder?

Comment: Where do I configure `devtool` when working with angular-cli?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187556/angular-cli-where-is-webpack-config-js-file-new-2017-feb-ng-eject

Comment: Actually, I don't know if this will help. According to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3113, It seems that in angular cli the default is `devtool: 'source-map''`, and I still see `webpack-internal://...`

Comment: I tested `devtool: 'source-map'` using webpack. That's why I'm certain that it works. I don't know angular-cli. If you run `ng --help` you can see that they provide a `--sourcemap` flag and that it can only be used to enable or disable source maps. Thus it looks like angular-cli does not allow to configure this.

Comment: From what I understand, `--sourcemap` is on by default. You can use `--no-sourcemap` to cancel it, but then I don't get my source files in the browser at all. With the default (or with --sourcemap), it seems angular cli sets `devtool: source-map` and I still get `webpack-internal://`... :(

Comment: OP was asking about webpack. I gave an answer which to the best of my knowledge is correct for OPs question. I specifically tested it even. So to the person who downvoted: Care to comment why you think this answer is not correct?

Comment: @splintor the PR you reference is outdated. Can you try making a production build with the `--sourcemap` flag?

Comment: I'll check but I'm more interested in debug build, not production. I see `webpack-internal` while I develop, and it annoys me. 

Also, I mistakenly downvoted it, and now SO won't let me upvote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: OK, I checked, and indeed, in prod build, I don't see `webpack-internal` (thanks!), but I do see it in debug build, even with `--sourcemap`, which is very annoying. Any idea what can be done?

Comment: Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge from looking at their source there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks, @ben, Can you explain the difference between prod and dev build, so I can open an issue for them?

Comment: The difference between dev and prod build comes from this file: https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_webpack/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.ts `buildOptions.optimization` is responsible for the choice of source map and you can clearly see that there are only two hard coded options of source maps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be resolved (or at least greatly improved) in Chrome 66.