# Webpack: Generate index.html for use with Django

Tags: javascript, django, angular, webpack

I have an Angular 4/Django application, all of the angular code in a Django application. The angular app is built using webpack.

I would like webpack to output the .js bundles into the "static" folder and an "index.html" file into the "templates" folder. The `<script></script>` tags that are injected will also need to be updated to use Django's "static files" notation:

```
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/polyfills.js' %}"></script>
```

Here is my directory structure (some files omitted for brevity), where `project` is the top-level holding the Django project.

```
project
    + angular
        + app (angular application root)
            + config
            + node_modules
            + src
            - webpack.config.js
        + static
            + dist ( webpack output folder)
                - app.[hash].js
                - vendor.[hash].js
                - polyfills.[hash.js
                - index.html
        + templates
                - index.html
```

- Note: I know I can copy/move the index.html quite easily, but I need the  tags to also use Django's static files.

For clarification. Here is my current "templates/index.html" file that is served by Django. This works fine as it is. I would like to have webpack generating this file if possible because I want to use the [hash] in the naming of the dis files and have that updated automatically here. So I would have `app.[hash].js`, `vendor.[hash].js`, `polyfill.[hash].js` and the Django template would be updated when my angular app is built by webpack.

templates/index.html

```
    {% load static %}
    <html>
      <head>
          <base href="/">
        <title>App</title>
        <link href="{% static 'dist/app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>

        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>


       <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/polyfills.js' %}"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/vendor.js' %}"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/app.js' %}"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is the wrong way round. The index.html should be a template which is rendered by Django and then used by Angular.

Comment: Yes, I understand and that is currently how I am implementing. What  I want  to accomplish is for webpack to generate the template file for Django so that I can generate bundles that have the [hash] in the name and django is aware of the file names.

Answer (score 3):

Webpack uses the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) to generate the templates. I've found a workaround (it feels hacky, and it's certainly an extra layer of work) which uses the webpack.config.js along with the django templates.

Note that Angular2/4/5/whatever doesn't give you access to its webpack config. Use `ng eject` (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42406194/7105494)) to extract it. The `webpack.config.js` below is an excerpt with modifications.

**DISCLAIMER** I've only ever used this with a Webpack + Django project. Changing the default Webpack config for Angular2 seems like a huge rabbit hole to go into. I would suggest avoiding this and using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) + Angular2 to completely separate the back-end from the front-end. But to each its own i guess; below is my solution:

```js
// webpack.config.js
// ...
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); // should already be here,
                                            // but it's the main player of this excerpt

module.exports = {
    // ...
    "entry": {
        "main": ["./src/main.ts"],
        "polyfills": ["./src/polyfills.ts"],
        "styles": ["./src/assets/css/styles.css"]
    },
    "output": {
        "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
        "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
        "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js",
        "publicPath": '/'             // <- this is new
    },
    // ...
    "plugins": [
        // ...
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            "template": "./templates/index.html", // <- path to your template
            "filename": "./path/of/output/file.html", // <- output html file
                                              // default  is './index.html'
            "inject": false // <- this allows you to place the static files
                            //    where you want them
     // ...
```

Then

```
# my_project.settings.py
# ...
# assuming your angular and django projects share the same base dir
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'src'), # <- this is webpack's output dir
)
```

Then in your template

```
<!-- templates/index.html -->
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>App</title>
    <link href="{% static 'dist/app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.polyfills.entry' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.vendor.entry' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.app.entry' %}"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

You will have to run django's `python manage.py collectstatic --clear` after every webpack build (in order to clean the 'static' folder).

Comment: Thanks, finally I figured how to prevent the plugin to inject JS wherever it wanted. I'd have a couple of questions left if you are still up to it: 1) Why the command `python manage.py collectstatic --clear`? It seems dangerous and am not sure it is useful. 2) Is there a way to make also webpack-dev-server serve the html content real time to Django or the plugin just builds?
(LOL for your nickname, in Italian it sounds quite funny)

Comment: @GiampaoloFerradini,  I'm quite certain the `collectstatic  --clear` is used to clean out the webpack output from the previous webpack bundle.  Webpack uses a unique hash each time, so the files would just build up everytime you ran it.