# Update to Angular v6 - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-universal, angular6

I'm trying to migrate my Angular Universal project from Angular v5 to v6

I've got a service where I use `fs` to load the translation on the server side. Everything works well with Angular v5.

With Angular v6, when I run `npm run start` aka `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` I face the following error

> ERROR in
>   ./src/providers/core/translate/translate-universal-loader.service.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   '/Users/me/Documents/projects/myproject/src/providers/core/translate'

In my service I declare `fs` like the following:

```
declare var require: any;
const fs = require('fs');
```

I also tried to declare it like following, but didn't help

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

To tell webpack to ignore fs I tried to add the following in my `webpack.server.config.js` without success

```
node: {
    fs: 'empty'
}
```

also tried with a webpack plugin, wasn't successful neither

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/fs/)
```

but actually it's maybe not the config use by `ng serve` but I don't know if I could still eject the configuration with v6?

anyone has got an idea?

**UPDATE**

If I declare fs as `any` it solves the problem for `ng serve` but unfortunately it will not work on the server side after `npm run build:ssr` and run `npm run serve`. On the server side I will then face the following error

> ERROR ReferenceError: fs is not defined

p.s.: my project follows https://github.com/angular/universal-starter structure, config and dependencies

Comment: try declaring the `fs` also, `declare var fs: any;`

Comment: cool that's a nice workaround which works, thx a lot @JohnVelasquez - I let you answer the question and will then mark it as the solution

Comment: try putting this condition when you're using `fs` -> `if(typeof window !== 'undefined')`

Comment: that won't help, the problem is on the server side, the code is also only use on the server side (isPlatformServer)

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57506728/11127383

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Update 2020**

See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63427821/5404186) of Marc for Angular v9.

**Update 2019**

See comment, according @Tahlil it is now possible. This works for Angular v8 (Ivy compiler) [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52367183/468910). It sets specific modules to false for use in the browser in package.json.

**Original answer**

Ok after hours I come to the conclusion with the answers I gathered that the real answer is:

You can't use `fs` anymore in Angular v6

Furthermore, since it's not possible anymore to eject the webpack configuration, there is no way to tell webpack to ignore the fs require

There is an open issue about this subject: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10681

P.S.: I was using fs to load the translations on the server side, I overcome the problem by following solution of @xuhcc, see https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/754

Comment: Turns out actually you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087330/angular-6-many-cant-resolve-errors-crypto-fs-http-https-net-path-stream

Comment: My answer is more than one year old. I added a comment in it.

Answer (score 59):

Since previous answers are quite old, it might help to highlight here that a workaround for Angular9 is just to add the following in your package.json:

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  }
```

This works very well for me.
For reference, I found this solution on the official tensorflow/tfjs Github page [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/753#issuecomment-466838806).

Comment: Coolio. Updated the accepted answer with a reference to yours.

Comment: The best answer for Angular 9+

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer one time for each false-positive solution I've found.  In my case it solved the error `ERROR in ./node_modules/foo/foo.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'my-app/node_modules/foo`, where `foo` is a module that uses `path`. :). In my case, only `"browser": { "path": false }` was needed.

Comment: Check the spec of the "browser" field to see why it works (or doesn't): https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec

Comment: Solves the build issue; however, my app does not properly load anymore `Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
    at Object.vbkW (index.js:4)`

Comment: Yea 2022 with 'file-system' module and this fix makes no difference. Anyone able to make this work with Angular 14?

Answer (score 15):

For anyone still looking for an answer, here's how I managed to require('fs') in my angular 7 app. Or for that matter, any other node module.

## Versions

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.4
Node: 10.13.0
OS: win32 x64
"@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
"@angular/cli": "~7.0.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
"electron": "^3.0.7",
"typescript": "~3.1.1"
```

#### 1. Install @types/node

`npm install --save-dev @types/node`

#### 2. Modify tsconfig.json

Take note of "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" flag. It must be set to true.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "strict": false
  }
}
```

#### 3. Require fs

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { } from 'electron';
import Fs from 'fs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    //check if platform is electron
    let isElectron: boolean = window && window['process'] && window['process'].type;

    if (isElectron) {
      let fs: typeof Fs = window['require']('fs');
      let app: Electron.App = window['require']('electron').remote;
      console.log(fs, app, window['process']);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: The import statements at the top of the file are just to provide for type information. The variable values are set using  node *`require`*.

### For updates, Track the issue here

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827

## Edit:

Turns out, that if your project has dependencies that *`require`*  `'fs', 'path', 'child_process'` etc. The angular compiler fails to compile the code. To get around this, as someone has already suggested,  add `(window as any).global = window;` to your polyfills.ts.

In my case, I had [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar), [node-pty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pty) and [electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron) as a dependency. This worker for me.

Comment: I have a project with a dependency that uses `path` and `fs`. I did the above mentioned steps but can't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hard to tell without any info, whats the version of angular, electron, nodejs that you're using?

Comment: I'm a lot closer than I was, but I'm getting an error `TypeError: window.require is not a function` when trying to use `window['require']`.  Not sure how to get around this one

Comment: @ntgCleaner try this:
`declare global {
    interface Window {
         require: NodeRequire;
   }
}`

Then, use window['require']. If it was a typescript compiler error, it must be solved with this. 

If that doesn't works, try this: `window['require']=eval('require')`. And the use window['require'].

Comment: @NishkalKashyap after trying what you've mentioned and playing around with it more, I just can't seem to get it to work.  I'm trying to do some simple web scraping with cheerio and request-promise, but they both need `require` to use.  I'll keep trying stuff out

Comment: @ntgCleaner try adding this code in electron creation function. it worked for me. `webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }`. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56095485/2342414)

Comment: works perfectly with electron 4.1.0, Ionic 5 and angular 8

Comment: This didn't work for me .. Marc's answer did. Thanks for sharing !

Answer (score 5):

In Angular 8, you can now use [Angular Builders](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) to specify a `web.config.js` which extends the virtual config produced by Angular.

[This blogpost](https://netbasal.com/customize-webpack-configuration-in-your-angular-application-d09683f6bd22) explains it quite well.

tldr:

1. run `npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack`
2. edit your `angular.json` file `architect.serve` and `architect.build` to tell it to use the `custom-webpack` module to extend the virtual config with your `webpack.config.js` file
3. Create your custom `webpack.config.js` - in this case it would look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
      }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

add below lines in your package.json

1. "browser": {
   "fs": false,
   "os": false,
   "path": false   }

[Click here to see sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXxKf.png)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct; you can't use `fs` anymore in Angular v6+.

However, this alternative builder (it's an extension to the Angular CLI) allows you to target an Electron environment and have full access to Electron's features:

https://github.com/angular-guru/electron-builder

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding

```
"types": [
  "node"
]
```

in tsconfig.app.json

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the `fs` also by doing this `declare var fs: any;`

Comment: actually, unfortunately, it doesn't fully solve the problem. this solve `ng serve` but if I build my project, `npm run build:ssr` and then run it `npm run serve`, I will face the error `fs is not defined` on the serve side :(

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively 
In NativeScript File is implemented as part of the file system module.
To use it you have to import it in your code behind file.
e.g.

```
import * as fs from "file-system';

var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
var path = fs.path.join(documents.path, "FileFromPath.txt");
var file = fs.File.fromPath(path);

// Writing text to the file.
file.writeText("Something")
    .then(function () {
        // Succeeded writing to the file.
    }, function (error) {
        // Failed to write to the file.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running an Angular app inside an Angular CLI monorepo, set up with the help of [Nx schematics](https://nx.dev/angular). I’m [sharing code from a lib directory](https://nx.dev/web/tutorial/07-share-code).

When trying to use a Typescript Enum from a shared lib inside the Angular app I got:

> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> Can't resolve 'fs'

The error stack involved:

- [type-graphql](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql), specifically [loadResolversFromGlob](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/801a4538aded6eb72a65829c2b39f8f1517617a4/src/helpers/loadResolversFromGlob.ts)
- [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob)
- [fs.realpath](https://github.com/isaacs/fs.realpath)

It was strange because on the face of if the inclusion of the Enum had nothing to do with type-graphql.

The issue turned out to be related to the fact that type-graphql schemas and Typescript Enums were defined in the same lib.  Extracting the Enums into their own lib solved the problem.  I’m not clear on why the error happened, but in any case the solution worked.

**EDIT**

So the problem was that per [this nx issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1384), and [this type-graphql issue](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/100), at a certain point including stuff from a lib with TypeGraphQL ends up trying to bundle whole TypeGraphQL into the browser app (the `@Input()` decorator seems to be another such trigger).

The solution, if you want to include TypeGraphQL classes in the frontend, is to [update the webpack config](https://typegraphql.ml/docs/browser-usage.html). Doing this is in an AngularCLI app [involves quite a few steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53910947/1450420).

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported jasmine in your spec file to avoid `tslint` error, you should to following:

1. Remove `import jasmine;` from spec file.
2. Add `jasmine` in `tsconfig.json`

```
...
...
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  ...
  "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jasmine"
  ]
  ...
  ...
}
...
...
```

Answer (score -3):

Apparently **advanced-json-path** resolves this issue in Angular 6 onwards if anyone is using fs

So one has to do an

```
npm i advanced-json-path --save-dev
```

as it is a dev dependency (at least in my case)
as of this message instance, it is version 1.0.8
Then the Module 'fs' not found doesn't occur.

```
package.json
{
    ....
   "advanced-json-path": "^1.0.8",
}
```

In our application it got rid of the Module 'fs' not found error.

Comment: why would advanced-json-path have anything to do with this?