# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, nem

I am getting the following list of errors when I run `ng serve`.

My package JSON is as follows:

```
{   "name": "ProName",   "version": "0.0.0",   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"   },   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.10",
    "@types/dotenv": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/errorhandler": "0.0.32",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.1",
    "apostille-library": "^7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.0",
    "nem2-sdk": "^0.9.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"   } }
```

The error I get :

> ERROR in ./node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '/Users/MYPC/Documents/Myproj/ProName/node_modules/aws-sign2' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'crypto' in '/Users/MYPC/Documents/Myproj/ProName/node_modules/aws4'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '/Users/MYPC/Documents/Myproj/ProName/node_modules/ecc-jsbn' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/verify.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '/Users/MYPC/Documents/Myproj/ProName/node_modules/http-signature/lib'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '/Users/MYPC/Documents/Myproj/ProName/node_modules/http-signature/lib'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/nem-sdk/build/external/nacl-fast.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '/Users/MYPC/Documents/Myproj/ProName/node_modules/nem-sdk/build/external'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/nem-sdk/node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js

Comment: @Illep Try installing globally.

Comment: @Variable `crypto` is a builtin module in node.js .

Comment: There are some other libaries that use it. How can I solve it?

Comment: I am using angular 8 and this solved the same issue when compiling using ng build --prod. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1548#issuecomment-478837014

Comment: Original answer came here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1548#issuecomment-450891241

Comment: I tried out with this solution try check out this :
[Click here ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71843843/5810125)

Answer (score 161):

I ran into a similar issue lately while trying to use another library ([tiff.js](https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js)) in a small project I was experimenting with.

The way I got around this was to add the following to my *package.json* file, right after the `devDependencies` section.

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
},
"browser": {
    "crypto": false
}
```

This didn't seem to have any adverse effect when trying to use the library in the application.

Comment: The reason this happens is because when your run `ng serve`, it bundles up the dependencies you have in your `package.json` to serve it on the browser. However, `package.json` generally includes both server and browser dependencies, and any native module dependency (like `crypto`) cannot be bundled to serve on the browser. Setting `'crypto': false` in the `browser` section of `package.json` tells `ng serve` not to attempt to bundle that file.

Comment: You might have to stop and restart the "ng serve" operation to make this effective. Thanks, it worked.

Comment: Great solution, unless you actually need to use the crypto library.

Comment: what if you want to use the crypt library, then what would be the solution for the above?

Comment: In my case I use webpack 5. I got a warning that explains why it happens and what to do: 

`BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }`

Comment: There is now an ES modules version called "crypto-es". It clears these warnings. https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-es

Comment: so where is resolve.fallback placed?  angular.json in one of the tiers?

Answer (score 57):

Adding this setting in **tsconfig.json** file under that project resolve this warning

```
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "crypto": [
    "node_modules/crypto-js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: the finame should be tsconfig.json

Comment: This worked for me. We couldn't use the browser.crypto = false fix on our project, but this worked and is acceptable by our Senior Devs.

Comment: That's the only solution that worked for me. The  browser.crypto=false didn't do anything

Comment: Worked for me and had to change the path

Comment: work for me, but i had to change "../../node_modules/crypto-js" to "node_modules/crypto-js". Angular 10 and partial import like import MD5 from 'crypto-js/md5';

Comment: If you actually need the crypto module, this is the cleanest solution. Setting to false will wreak havoc if you are using token-based auth in your static app.

Comment: This worked for me, as indeed the package I'm importing needs to use `crypto` module.

Comment: the code snippet is missing one more closing brace at the end to close the compilerOptions :)

Answer (score 40):

I like [R. Richards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5437671/r-richards)'s answer, but I thought it would be useful to provide some more information.

This is a known issue with Angular, and the Angular CLI dev team seems to think it's a feature rather than a bug. I, as well as other developers in [this issue thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1548), disagree. Contributors to that thread provided several workaround fixes, but my project didn't compile successfully until I implemented R. Richards' solution. I didn't revert the previous changes, though, so [tacnoman](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1548#issuecomment-415442798)'s and [GrandSchtroumpf](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1548#issuecomment-450891241)'s fixes may be of use to others.

Some, like [clovis1122](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6432398/clovis1122) here and others in that issue thread, have questioned why a web app would need access to these libraries and why the necessary tasks can't be completed on the server side instead. I can't speak for everyone, but my use case is that, when authenticating a user account, Strapi responds with a JSON Web Token string that must be decoded by the client. Since [the necessary library](https://jwt.io/) depends on `crypto` and `stream`, you won't be able to extract the JWT expiration time unless those dependencies are available.

In case anyone has trouble extrapolating from R. Richards' answer, you'll have to set to false any dependencies that are showing up in "can't resolve x" errors. For example, the critical part of my package.json is:

```
    "browser": {
        "crypto": false,
        "stream": false
    }
```

Answer (score 30):

I thought I would expand on what Tarique Ahmed wrote in his answer.

I was using an npm module that had the following line in the code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
```

I couldn't add:

```
"browser": {
  "crypto": false
}
```

to the package.json because the `crypto` package had to be part of the build.

It turns out that during the compilation process Angular seems to have decided to install the `crypto-browserify` package instead of `crypto`.

Adding the following to the `tsconfig.json` file instructs the build to use the `crypto-browserify` library every time that `crypto` is required. As you can see, I had the same issue for the `stream` package.

```
"paths": {
  "crypto": [
    "node_modules/crypto-browserify"
  ],
  "stream": [
    "node_modules/stream-browserify"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is the most clear and precise solution provided. Just installed and used `crypto-browserify` instead of `crypto` and made *tsconifg.json* as mentioned above.

Answer (score 21):

If you upgraded to Webpack 5, you need to add this to your **webpack config file**:

```
resolve: {
    fallback: { crypto: false },
},
```

Comment: +1 This works as current angular 12, `node: { crypto: false } ` is deprecated.
You need to merge a webpack.config.ts with @angular-builders/custom-webpack

Comment: @LucaFagioli I've been seen this solution but I don't have a webpack config or at least I don't see it

Comment: @RicardoSanchezSantos Webpack can actually work without a configuration file. You need to create one. Check [this page](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) for support.

Comment: List of polyfills you can use to fix this - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Answer (score 18):

After having the same issue with Angular 11 and crypto-js 4 (and manually setting the path in tsconfig.json), I found rolling back crypto-js to version 3.1.9-1 fixed the issue. It seems a change made in version 4 caused the issue.

```
npm install crypto-js@3.1.9-1
```

Explained here in repo issues:

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/291)

Comment: I had the same issue and it works for me. I work with Angular 11 and I had installed the 4.0 crypto version.

Comment: I had the same issue with Angular 11 and I had crypto-js verion 4.0.
I confirm that this is the solution for that case.

Answer (score 3):

My Error

[image]

In my Case the `import { get } from "express/lib/response"` is the culprit, which is automatically added by vs-code.
So, after removing it I solved my issue

[image]

Answer (score 3):

crypto is a Node.js module hence it wouldn't work on Angular. I'm sure there might be an alternative way or you can use Node.js with Angular. crypto module will work on Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

`aws-sign2` is a NodeJS package (and `crypto` is a NodeJS module), but it looks like you're dealing with a web application. It makes sense that the `crypto` module is not available in that environment.

Would it be possible to complete what you need to do server-side? Otherwise, you may need to look for another package.

Answer (score 2):

Using direct import may not work with ES6 Enviornment..

This may help you.

`$ npm i crypto-js@latest` // For using latest version 4

```
import AES from 'crypto-js/aes';
import Utf8 from 'crypto-js/enc-utf8';
import { secretKey } from './environments/environment';

/** Encryption */
const data = {key: 'Test Value'};
const ciphertext = AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), secretKey).toString();
console.log('Encrypted Data', ciphertext);

/** Decryption */
const bytes = AES.decrypt(ciphertext, secretKey);
const decryptedData = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(Utf8));
console.log('Decrypted Data', decryptedData);
```

https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/168#issuecomment-785617218

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel Inertia JS project, my solution was:

1- Add dependencies to package.json

```
   "dependencies": {
        "crypto-browserify": "3.12.0",
        "crypto-random-string": "^3.3.0",
        "stream": "^0.0.2"
    }
```

2-In webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
        },
        fallback: {
            crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
            stream: require.resolve('stream'),
        },
    },
};
```

3-Install, build and run:

```
npm install && npm run watch
```

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved my issue using below steps:

Add below to **tsconfig.json** to resolve crypto warning:

```
"paths": {
      "crypto": [
        "node_modules/crypto-js"
      ]
    },
```

and add below to **angular.json**

```
"options": {
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "crypto-js"
            ],
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## **QUASAR FRAMEWORK v2**

Just in case you are using Quasar v2, the working solution is to just update the quasar.config.js `build` :

```
module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
  build: {
      chainWebpack (chain) {
          const nodePolyfillWebpackPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin')
          chain.plugin('node-polyfill').use(nodePolyfillWebpackPlugin)
          chain.resolve.alias.set('crypto', require.resolve('crypto-browserify'))

       }
   
})
```

Comment: If you get an error message that node-polyfill-webpack-plugin is missing (like I got), run ```npm install node-polyfill-webpack-plugin --save``` and then the above works like a charm. Thank you @Reamon!

Comment: Welcome! I'm glad it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs into this in 2023 and is using Next middleware: you can't currently use crypto in the Vercel edge middleware environment.

I was trying to use jsonwebtoken to sign a token which uses crypto under the hood, so it didn't work. So I installed [jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose) instead. Jose is an JSON Object Signing and Encryption library that *does* currently work in the middleware edge environment. And it solved the issue for me!

See [this post](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38227) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Alot of answers already but still none of them works. In my case I see warning message

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.  If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:         - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'         - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:         resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

comment from @stewii did helped me to resolved this.

There is now an ES modules version called "crypto-es". It clears these warnings. [npmjs.com/package/crypto-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-es)

After this I imported `cryptoES`

```
import CryptoES from 'crypto-es';
```

and remove the existing import of `cryptoJs`. Re-start the compile and Voila.. The warning message is gone.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using angular 16.

Answer (score 1):

When using #Laravel framework with Laravel Mix this is going to be more trick. I spend some hours on this NPM nightmare and found a solid solution.

So, in your webpack.mix.js you find the 'comment'

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
```

Now just below that comment add the following lines;

```
mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                exports: {
                    resolve: {
                        fallback: {
                            crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    };
});
```

Now you can use Laravel Mix just like you would edit webpack.config.js ;)
Also; In package.json remove:

```
--no-progress --hide-modules
```

These are no longer valid for WebPack >= 5. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

After a deep a research i found that the solution is very simple: replace
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'; with declare var  CryptoJS;

Comment: How does the application know where to get Crypto, if the 'from' part is skipped?

Answer (score 0):

Add the option allowedCommonJsDependencies with literal "crypto-js" in a array, this in file angular.json:

```
"architect": 
        "build": {              
          "options": {               
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "crypto-js"
            ]
          },
         }
 }
```

This will disable all warnings, tested in Angular 11.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was trying to build to node and web using the same code, but is not possible to built to web while importing a WebSocket dependency, [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) in my case

So the solution is by using a wrapper:

Install a wrapper, I will use [isomorphic-ws](https://github.com/heineiuo/isomorphic-ws) because is made for [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws)

```
npm i --save isomorphic-ws
```

Remove `const WebSocket = require('ws')`

Replace with:

```
const WebSocket = require('isomorphic-ws')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going into

node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

and adding:

```
fallback: {
        // Here paste
        crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
        http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
        url : require.resolve("url")
      }
```

And now my react app builds with errors but no dependency issues. Ill update this when I get it building.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
npm install crypto-js
```

Or Add a specific version according to your project need

```
npm install crypto-js@4.0.0
```

Also, run the above commands in Window "run as administrator"  or in Linux use sudo

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of the solutions above but the final thing that worked for me was downloading the crypto-es package and adding, `"type":"module"` to package.json.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-es

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, Just run `node patch.js` and it worked. The issue is, browser doesn't allow server files to be run on browser. In case you need some of these, You can use `node patch.js`. If you don't want to run any server file on browser, you can simply apply above mentioned solution by @R.Richards. Might be helpful for someone..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution described by [R.Richards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5437671/r-richards) doesn't work.
However, following several threads along this issue, I finally understood where to insert the recommendation provided in the warning message and solved this warning.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js 64:13-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\PC\Documents\3 - Projet MAKAO\dev\RepoAlecol\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

**If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }**
```

Differently from many contributors, I didn't want to install crypto-browserify as I don't need it (*), and I chose to add the fallback { "crypto": false }.
**However I didn't know where to add this fallback. After reading several threads, I found it was in the webpack.config.js file, which is located in the directory node_modules/react_scripts/config**.
Adding this fallback made the compilation succeed without any warning.

(*) PS : I once tried to add the following fallback  { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }, but it led to generation of 7 errors, requiring other modules :

```
    Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\PC\Documents\3 - Projet MAKAO\dev\RepoAlecol\node_modules\cipher-base'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 2:16-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\PC\Documents\3 - Projet MAKAO\dev\RepoAlecol\node_modules\cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js 43:13-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\PC\Documents\3 - Projet MAKAO\dev\RepoAlecol\node_modules\readable-stream\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
        - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js 65:13-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\PC\Documents\3 - Projet MAKAO\dev\RepoAlecol\node_modules\readable-stream\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
        - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/buffer_list.js 63:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\PC\Documents\3 - Projet MAKAO\dev\RepoAlecol\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\internal\streams'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
        - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/ripemd160/index.js 3:13-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\PC\Documents\3 - Projet MAKAO\dev\RepoAlecol\node_modules\ripemd160'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
        - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 3:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\PC\Documents\3 - Projet MAKAO\dev\RepoAlecol\node_modules\safe-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
        - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/safer-buffer/safer.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\PC\Documents\3 - Projet MAKAO\dev\RepoAlecol\node_modules\safer-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
        - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

webpack compiled with 7 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue in React and searched a lot and Got a solution for this which worked and I resolved this issue. The following is the solution for this:

**Step-1:**
Install `react-app-rewired` and the missing modules into your application

```bash
npm install --save-dev react-app-rewired crypto-browserify stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify os-browserify url buffer process
```

**Step-2:**
Create `config-overrides.js` in the root of your project folder with the content:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function override(config) {
  const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
  Object.assign(fallback, {
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    assert: require.resolve("assert"),
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    os: require.resolve("os-browserify"),
    url: require.resolve("url"),
  });
  config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
  config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
  ]);
  config.ignoreWarnings = [/Failed to parse source map/];
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
    enforce: "pre",
    loader: require.resolve("source-map-loader"),
    resolve: {
      fullySpecified: false,
    },
  });
  return config;
};
```

**Step-3:**
Within `package.json`, change the scripts field for start, build, and test. Instead of `react-scripts`, replace it with `react-app-rewired`.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Answer (score -3):

I had this problem in ReactJS with create-react-app(facebook)

Solution:

1. First install the necessary packages "crypto-browserify"
2. Modify webpack.config.js in reactjs with create-react-app this file is inside:

> node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

- Search module.exports and inside this function there is a return:

```js
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  ...
  return {
   ...
    resolve: {
      ...
      fallback: {
        // Here paste
        crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Is possible you need other packages how "stream-browserify" the steps are same. This solution works, but when the webpack project starts it shows warnings

Pd: I am not native speaker English, but I hope understand me.