# How do I resolve the "Module not found" error for crypto + other dependencies (Angular 9)

Tags: node.js, angular, web-applications, angular9, cryptojs

I am working on making an Angular app (Angular 9) as a side project. However, this one issue keeps persisting. Every time I try to run `ng serve`, I'm prompted with a ton of these errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'node_modules/request/lib'
```

There are dozens of these same kinds of errors for `crypto`, `fs`, `http`, `https`, `stream`, `tls`, and `zlib` as well. I have ran `npm install ...` for all of these dependencies and they are in my node_modules folder. I've tried following some of the suggestions posted here (https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs/issues/17) and following this thread ([Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162297/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-crypto/54162447)) such as updating my package.json to include after my devDependencies:

```
"browser": {
"crypto": false,
"stream": false,
"fs": false,
"http": false,
"https": false,
"tls": false,
"zlib": false
},
```

I also have in my tsconfig.json:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"downlevelIteration": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es2015",
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom"
],
"types": ["node"],...
```

I get no compiler errors, but the console in the browser screams:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at Object../node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js (:4200/vendor.js:114108)
at __webpack_require__ (:4200/runtime.js:80)
at Object../node_modules/request/index.js (:4200/vendor.js:113314)
at __webpack_require__ (:4200/runtime.js:80)
```

When I take a peek into the readme in the crypto folder in my node modules, it said that is has been deprecated and that I should switch to the built-in Node module. I can't seem to find anything that explains how to tell Node to use its built-in crypto. Am I missing something here?

There seems to also be more discussion about this issue (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1548) but I'm unaware of anything getting resolved? Does anyone have any workarounds? If the issue is with Node, how can I tell it to use the built-in crypto dependency?

Thanks!

Update:

From angular.json:

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "myproject:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "myproject:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: can you post your `ng serve` angular.json section please?
Does `ng build` works?

Comment: For sure, I added it above! `ng build` works fine if I have the `browser` options in my package.json, but without that I get: `Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration`