# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular

Error Message:

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

So I was googling this issue and had a LOT of problems finding a solution. So i would like to share it with you:

1. First of all this can happen not only with crypto but other stuff like http, https, os and so on.
2. Check if the packet (this case crypto-browserify is installed) There should be a folder node_modules\crypto-browserify

If it doesnt exist: `npm install crypto browsrify`, then `yarn add @types/node@15.12.5 -D` (for this node version)

In node_modules\crypto-browserify edit package.json and add

```json
 , 
 "optionalDependencies": {},
 "browser": {
   "crypto": false
 },
```

(after devDependencies)

3. under tsconfig.json add

```json
"compilerOptions": {
"paths":{
   "crypto":["node_modules/crypto-browserify"],
   "http":["node_modules/stream-http"],
   "https":["node_modules/https-browserify"]
   },
```

4. under angluar.json add

```json
"architect": {
   "build": {
   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
   "options": {
      "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["crypto"],
      "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["http"],
      "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["https"],
```

Comment: BTW can somebody please tell me how to share a full block of code. stackoverflow told me to use "`" every line..

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: Uses triple backticks to start a code block, and then again to close it. I also put `json` after the opening three backticks to get the correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: This would be better rearranged as a self-answer: give just the error message in the question, and then all the config changes as an answer.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/67076572/841830 a simpler solution? Or solving a different problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in ReactJS with create-react-app(facebook)

Solution:

1. First install the necessary packages "crypto-browserify"
2. Modify webpack.config.js in reactjs with create-react-app this file is inside:

> node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

- Search module.exports and inside this function there is a return:

```js
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  ...
  return {
   ...
    resolve: {
      ...
      fallback: {
        // Here paste
        crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note:Is possible that need more packages, for example "stream-browserify" the steps are same. This solution works, but when the webpack project starts it shows warnings

Pd: I am not native speaker English, but I hope understand me.