# How to use Quasar 2 with AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-amplify, vuejs3, quasar

I have created the following boot file for Quasar in `src/boot/amplify.js` and added `'amplify'` to `quasar.conf.js`:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from '../aws-exports';
import {
  applyPolyfills,
  defineCustomElements,
} from '@aws-amplify/ui-components/loader';

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
  defineCustomElements(window);
});
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

But I get many import errors from the line `import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';`:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "./printError"        

 App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./node_modules/graphql/error/GraphQLError.mjs
```

And more -- I've gotten passed them with `npm install --save graphql`, but I then found many more errors for the import.  It is easy to setup following Amplify docs using Vue 3 CLI and not Quasar.

Anyone had luck using Quasar or know what a possible solution might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is a webpack issue, check this:
https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/2721#issuecomment-723008284

I solved it by adding to the quasar.conf.js

```
build: {
...
extendWebpack (cfg, {isServer, isClient}) {
        cfg.module.rules.push ({
          test: /\.m?js/,
          resolve: {
            fullySpecified: false,
            fallback: {crypto: false}
          }
        })
      }
    }
}
```

the "fallback : {crypto: false}"
it is used to resolve the subsequent error about the missing dependency of crypto-js based on:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67076572/1550140

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I got a similar response here.  Working now, thanks again!
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8567