# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, solana

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/@solana/spl-name-service/dist/utils.js 16:17-34

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@solana\spl-name-service\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

**Where the problem started:**

- I tried using getParsedNftAccountsByOwner() from:
  https://github.com/NftEyez/sol-rayz
- Then, I got this error message.

**My project:**

- getParsedNftAccountsByOwner()
- React, Typescript project
- Libraries used: @solana/web3.js **|** @nfteyez/sol-rayz
- webpack 5.67.0

**Even though I was able to resolve these errors in a few minutes, the 'crypto' one is different:**

*Stream problem:*

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```

*assert problem:*

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@solana/spl-name-service/dist/utils.js 14:33-50

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@solana\spl-name-service\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }
```

**What I have done so far:**

1. I tried performing the two suggestions from the error message, and it didn't work
2. I tried the first two solutions already:

   "compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": "./",
   "paths": {
   "crypto": [
   "node_modules/crypto-js"
   ]
   }

[Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162297/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-crypto)

3. I tried this solution:

   "browser": {
   "crypto": false
   }

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/494#issuecomment-481636128

4. I tried this solution: node-polyfill-webpack-plugin

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65556946/18007508

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")
module.exports = {
        // Other rules...
        plugins: [
            new NodePolyfillPlugin()
        ]
    }
```

**My Code:**
*webpack.config.js*

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/components/index.tsx",
  target: "web",
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(\__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    fallback: {
      "crypto":require.resolve('crypto-browserify') ,
    } 
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
      },
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "css-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(\__dirname, "src", "components", "index.html"),
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "./src/yourfile.css",
    }),
    new NodePolyfillPlugin()
  ],
};
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.3",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@nfteyez/sol-rayz": "^0.9.1",
    "@nfteyez/sol-rayz-react": "^0.9.1",
    "@solana/spl-name-service": "^0.1.3",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.2",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.2",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.4",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.14.2",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.32.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.19",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "browser": "^0.2.6",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "store": "^2.0.12",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "three": "^0.136.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.22",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.20",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.15",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that because your create react app (CRA) does not recognize your `webpack.config.js`. Your setting for polyfills is correct. Setting up `node-polyfill-webpack-plugin` itself is enough to load all node core polyfills.

In order to modify the `webpack.config.js` in CRA, you have to run

```
   npm run eject
```

this will create a `config` directory and inside you will have `webpack.config.js` which has almost 1000 lines of code. Inside that file, setting up `node-polyfill-webpack-plugin` should be enough.

Comment: there are major consequences to eject, I would recommend reading about it before you do it