# module not found, React

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem when I run the `npm start` command.
the following errors are displayed:

> Compiled with problems:X
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 4:13-30
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/cookie-signature'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and
> configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "crypto": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 12:17-41
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/destroy'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 18:13-30
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
> '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/etag'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "crypto": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:12-31
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/etag'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 28:11-26
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in
> '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/express/lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
> - install 'stream-http' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: { "http": false
>   }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 22:11-26
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in
> '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/express/lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
> - install 'stream-http' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: { "http": false
>   }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 23:11-26
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in
> '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/express/lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
> - install 'stream-http' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: { "http": false
>   }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 18:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/express/lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 3:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/mime'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/send'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js 1:0-43
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in
> '/home/mpeubey/Oncobase/front2/node_modules/zlib/lib'

I tried to delete node_modules and `npm i`, but the problem persists.

I also tried to install the packages separately but idem, the problem is still there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162297/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-crypto)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to pack Node-only packages into a react app.

Comment: no, this doesn't answer my question

Comment: problem solved, I had put by mistake an express module in my react component

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1

Install path-browserify, browserify-zlib, stream-http, crypto-browserify and react-app-rewired

```sh
npm install path-browserify browserify-zlib stream-http crypto-browserify react-app-rewired
```

### Step 2

In your project root, create `config-overrides.js` file.

In this file, put this.

```js
module.exports = function override (config, env) {
    console.log('override...')
    let loaders = config.resolve
    loaders.fallback = {
        "fs": false,
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
        "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") ,
        "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
    }
    
    return config
}
```

### Step 3

**important !**

Change `"start": react-scripts start` in your package.json to `"start": react-app-rewired start`

## Now, restart your project.

```sh
npm start
```

Comment: I still get errors after doing this. `Error: Can't resolve 'querystring'`

Answer (score 0):

Any module not found You Can perform 3 steps first

First :

`npm install modulename`

OR

`yarn add modulename`

Second:

`delete node_module && package-lock.json`

run `npm install or yarn add`,

Third :

Error not solve goto package.json specify

`dependency{package:"latest"}`

or specify dependency version as per requirement and check that dependency or library you are using that is in the list

`dependency{package:"^*.*.*"}`

and follow step 2

and a specific solution check that on which specific `npm & node` version the app is build then install that version of `npm & node`

If that not solve the error then there is programming error or something else.

Specific in your case check each dependencies

HOPE YOUR PROBLEM CAN BE SOLVE