# Error when importing the Crypto module in Javascript. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'

Tags: javascript, cryptography, cryptojs

When I attempt and import crypto, I keep getting this error message on React.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'
```

This is the current code:

```
const { createHash } = require('crypto');

function calculateIdHash(input) {
    return createHash('sha256').update(input).digest('hex');
}
```

I even tried `import { createHash } from 'crypto'`, and the same error message popped up.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the different solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162297/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-crypto

Comment: what nodejs version are you using ? in docs said you can check if your nodejs support crypto by using a try-catch syntax. Take a look at [this](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto) link