# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto', webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-build

I was trying to build the react project using npm run build but it failed with the following messages.

```
❯ npm run build

> coin-web-test2@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/...../node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to configure `config-overrides.js` and `webpack.config.js` with these commands
(thanks to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162297/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-crypto))

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { crypto: false },
  },
};
```

However, I'm still receiving the same error.

Later on, I found that the default `react-scripts` bundled in node_module contains it's own webpack.config.js and it may interfere with mine. Not sure about this tbh. Would be nice if someone can explain.

And eventually, I changed the "scripts" in package.json to this and the error finally disappeared

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js build",
    ....
  },
```