# Electron: crypto not defined

Tags: electron

Hello – my electron app has one user experiencing the error below.  He's on Windows 10, and has reproduced it on two separate machines.  I can't reproduce, nor have any other users reported this issue.  The electron app is signed for Windows using a Comodo CA certificate.  Originally, it occurred for him only when using electron's built-in autoupdate feature.  Now that he's on the latest version, it occurs at launch – again, on two machines.

UPDATE: I have a second user reporting this now, though I still can't reproduce myself.

I can't seem to find anyone else posting with this error exactly, though I've tried changing the webpack require fallbacks, setting `"browser": { "crypto": false }`, and a few other things for similar errors (from [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162297/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-crypto)).

[image]

I'd love some direction to figure out what's going on here and what the fix should be.

Comment: I find it interesting that the error occurs at a string replace operation. Have you tried identifying where the exception comes from? Is it potentially your code or a library/Electron code compiled into your app's ASAR? (It may be worth trying to reproduce the same error without packaging the app into an ASAR, that way you would have a better chance of identifying the cause/problematic code.)