# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , tslib_1.__exportStar) is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

Trying to add @aws-amplify/ui-angular to my application and no matter what I try I get this error. When I click on main.js this is what shows up. I have tried changing node versions, upgrading and downgrading amplify/type script versions.

using:

```
"typescript": "~4.8.4"
"@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^4.0.1", // tried 4.0.4 as well
"aws-amplify": "^5.3.3",
```

```
/*!***********************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/@aws-crypto/sha256-js/build/index.js ***!
  \***********************************************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, exports, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";


Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", ({
  value: true
}));
var tslib_1 = __webpack_require__(/*! tslib */ 29501);
(0, tslib_1.__exportStar)(__webpack_require__(/*! ./jsSha256 */ 12008), exports);
```

`(__webpack_require__(/*! ./jsSha256 */ 12008), exports);` this is red underlined

EDIT: adding tsconfig.json, per comment request

```
{
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [ "es2018", "dom", "esnext" ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "paths": {
      "@core/*": [ "src/app/core/*" ],
      "@shared/*": [ "src/app/shared/*" ],
      "@services/*": [ "src/app/shared/services/*" ],
      "@enums/*": [ "src/app/types/enums/*" ],
      "@interfaces/*": [ "src/app/types/interfaces/*" ],
      "@mocks/*": [ "src/app/types/mocks/*" ],
      "@classes/*": [ "src/app/types/classes/*" ],

      // crypto browser warning fix...
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162297/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-crypto
      "crypto": [
        "node_modules/crypto-js"
      ]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./amplify",
    "./config/**/*",
    "./coverage/**/*",
    "./dist",
    "./e2e",
    "./node_modules",
    "./scripts",
    ".serverless",
    ".webpack/**/*",
    "_warmup/**/*",
    ".vscode/**/*",
    ".idea/**/*",
    "commitlint.config.js",
    "aws-exports.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Either disable [--importHelpers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#importHelpers) or install `install tslib` with your package manager. The latter approach is preferable.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have `"tslib": "^2.3.0",` installed in dependencies

Comment: Well, that version is out of date but that shouldn't be the issue. You should include your typescript configuration. I think the issue is actually that the generated code is trying to call a module namespace object. That's not valid code.

Comment: I added the config. How would I go about finding a module namespace call?

Comment: It appears to be in code that's being generated by webpack and typescript. First off, make sure you have only one version of tslib installed, including transitively. `npm ls tslib`. Also, in your tsconfig.json enable `esModuleInterop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was simply pointing to an incorrect tslib location in my tsconfig.json. Removing it solved the issue.