# Mapbox not works global is not defined

Tags: angular, mapbox

I dont know why getting this error all the time, tryed many times bypass it.
Maybe who knowing solution and haved this error?

app.module

```
NgxMapboxGLModule.withConfig(
      {token added..
          }),
```

package

```
  "mapbox-gl": "^0.52.0",
    "ngx-mapbox-gl": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^0.51.4",
    "@mapbox/geojson-area": "^0.2.2",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^3.1.6",
    "@mapbox/simplespec-to-gl-style": "^0.3.2",


index.js:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js (index.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/sha.js/hash.js (hash.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/sha.js/sha.js (sha.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/sha.js/index.js (index.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution from [ngx-mapbox-gl README](https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl):

> Add this in your polyfill.ts file
>   (https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl/issues/136#issuecomment-496224634):
>
> (window as any).global = window;

ngx-mapbox-gl depends on sha.js which calls 'global' which isn't available in the browser (it's a Node.js variable). The above code polyfills 'global' to be 'window' (which is available in the browser). Part of the wider range of issues caused by Angular 6 and above removing webpack's polyfills for Node.js specific variables and libraries (crypto, http, etc.)

[Angular 6 many Can't resolve errors (crypto, fs, http, https, net, path, stream, tls, zlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087330/angular-6-many-cant-resolve-errors-crypto-fs-http-https-net-path-stream)

[Related section at bottom of this article](https://www.amadousall.com/angular-cli-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve/)