# Using imported function is crashing web worker

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, web-worker

I have an electron app running angular 8+. I'm calling a function imported from `node_modules`. If I call this function directly in my component, it works fine. If I try to call the same function in a web worker, it fails the build.

```
// component file
const worker = new Worker('./dead-link-checker.worker', { type: 'module' });
        worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
            console.log(`page got message: ${data}`);
        };
        worker.postMessage({
            domainName: this.domainName,
            links: this.linksService.links
        });
```

```
// webworker file
import { deadLinkChecker } from 'dead-link-checker';
import { tester } from './test';

addEventListener('message', async ({ data }) => {
  console.log('in the workerer', data);

  // Breaks everything
  await deadLinkChecker(data.domainName, undefined, data.links);

  // Works fine
  tester();
  postMessage('link checking complete', undefined);
});
```

The error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/dead-link-checker.worker.ts (./node_modules/worker-plugin/dist/loader.js!./src/app/dead-link-checker.worker.ts)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/worker-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\aws-sign2'
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:823:10
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:397:22
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:6877:13
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:184:12
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\js_scripts\jordan-does-link-checking-electron\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38
```

I've had this kind of error before using nodejs scripts in angular and I have used solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087330/angular-6-many-cant-resolve-errors-crypto-fs-http-https-net-path-stream) to resolve it. This doesn't seem to be the same issue here because the imported `deadLinkChecker` function works fine if I use it outside of the web worker.

Comment: it looks like your module is not found: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'

Comment: @JohnKane Hey John! Thanks for taking a look. It finds the module without any problems if I call `deadLinkChecker` from within the component vs from within the webworker.

Comment: is it a different path to teh deadLinkChecker from within the webworker vs the component?

Comment: @JohnKane Good question. It is not. It's a `node_modules` module imported the same way in both files.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @RyanBiwer Sorry, I really can't remember. I don't believe so.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually ended up finding a fix here: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin/issues/75

Comment: @RyanBiwer Glad to hear it! Thanks for sharing.