# Angular - How to import googleapis library?

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I'm trying to incorporate the Google Drive API into one of my projects. The Node.js [quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) requires me to import file-reading and googleapis libraries. However, when I try to do so, I run into issues when importing it into app.module.ts or any components: 
Components import code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {google, drive_v3} from 'googleapis'
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3'});
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SubscriptionService {
  constructor () {}
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '...\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/crypto/node/crypto.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '...\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\crypto\node'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '...\node_modules\jwa'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '...\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '...\node_modules\google-p12-pem\build\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/discovery.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '...\node_modules\googleapis-common\build\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '...\node_modules\gtoken\build\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/agent-base/patch-core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '...\node_modules\agent-base'
ERROR in ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '...\node_modules\https-proxy-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '...\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '...\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '...\node_modules\gaxios\build\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '...\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '...\node_modules\googleapis-common\build\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '...\node_modules\jws\lib'ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '...\node_modules\jws\lib'ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '...\node_modules\jws\lib'ERROR in ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '...\node_modules\https-proxy-agent'
```

How do I properly import the googleapis library in Angular? I've tried adding the following script import to index.html as lots of people online suggest, but it doesn't seem to work (see comments).

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>`

I have also made sure to perform the following installs:

```
npm install --save @types/gapi
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
npm install --save @types/gapi.client.drive
```

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to work` ← That is not a helpful description of the symptom. Please describe the error or actual result in detail. Include the expected result as well.

Comment: You can't use node libraries in the front end. The second snippet will work but need more info.

Comment: Adding the `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>` line into the `index.html` file seems to makes no difference - it throws no additional errors. Supposedly it is meant to provide an external path to the library that will allow it to run, however the above error still occurs

Comment: @Phix Do I need to declare the script as a dependency somewhere else as well, or add a namespace?

Comment: That just loads the Google API, you'll need to do something with it once it loads. Check [this example from the docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js). `googleapis` is meant to be run in a Node environment, hence the errors which are trying to load other node packages.

Comment: Hi ! Have you followed accordingly the guide linked by @Phix ? Are you starting the web server? If you have a backend for this project I recommend you run this on the backend. Also, what is being implement under the ```script``` tag on the browser guide in the ```index.html``` could be run in the desired component ```.ts``` file.

Comment: any luck? I am facing the same issue. thanks

Comment: used lib - @google-cloud/storage with angular 9

Comment: @NileshMistry it apparently isn't possible to do this at all using the `googleapis` npm library. You should check out https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js for how to do it using gapi. I just used the gapi namespace in my code and it seemed to work. Unfortunately this project was from a while ago so it's hard for me to explain all the details because I would have to study my code again.

Comment: From what I understand you want to create a front end application. Then node.js won't making the calls. There is no sense in trying to integrate the googleapis  npm library (backend) to work inside in Angular (the frontend). Could you maybe post an answer, or if you want I can create a community wiki answer to help other users.

Comment: @NileshMistry, Found any solution? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

`googleapis` (and `google-auth-library`) is a NodeJS library. You can't use it in front-end projects as is. There're some workarounds - see https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/google-apis-with-angular-214fadb8fbc5 (but I didn't try it personally so can't recommend).
The other lib you mentioned - https://apis.google.com/js/api.js - is the right one, it's for front-end, but it's not modularized, it's just one big script that you need to load via script tag. That's because you cannot import it via `import`. To make TS compiler happy (providing you already installed types `@types/gapi*`) add this import in a file where you accessing `gapi` global object:

```
/// <reference types="gapi.client. drive" />
```