# Issues with dependencies of "web-request" package. Can't resolve 'stream', 'tls', 'zlib', 'path', 'net', 'https', 'http', 'fs', 'crypto'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest

I'm quite the beginner when it comes to developing web/node.js applications (so apologies if I am not explaining myself well enough) and am now working on an angular and angular material project. I **think** this is beside the point however...

My application is written in typescript - however I am using a typescript library that was compiled to javascript. This library uses "web-request". So far I am only using one file from this library (but this file uses others from the same library) which I will name "file_1.js" by doing `import { MyClass } from '../../lib/file_1'` and `myclass = new MyClass();`.

`file_1.d.ts` and `file_1.js.map` exist as well and I can only assume they are implemented properly. In fact, I have copy-pasted this library from a react project that I worked on a while back and it worked just fine there.

file_1.js only uses this library in two instances: therefore has:

```
const WebRequest = require("web-request");
let response = yield WebRequest.get(openUri, requestOptions);
let response = yield WebRequest.post(postUri, requestOptions, jsonBody);
```

I am very confident the library itself is sound. When trying to run my server via `ng serve` I get a ton of issues with dependencies of web-request not being resolved:

```
Error: ./node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/aws-sign2'

Error: ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/aws4'

Error: ./node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/ecc-jsbn'

Error: ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/http-signature/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/verify.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/http-signature/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/oauth-sign/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/oauth-sign'

Error: ./node_modules/request/lib/oauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/request/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/request/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/request/lib/hawk.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/request/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/identity.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/fingerprint.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/signature.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/private-key.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/certificate.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/key.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/dhe.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/pem.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/ssh-private.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats'

Error: ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/openssh-cert.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats'

Error: ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/request/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/home/ubuntu/my_website/node_modules/request'
```

I tried applying the solution suggested by snorberhuis here: [Angular 6 many Can't resolve errors (crypto, fs, http, https, net, path, stream, tls, zlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087330/angular-6-many-cant-resolve-errors-crypto-fs-http-https-net-path-stream) by adding this to my package.json:

```
  "browser": {
    "http": false,
    "https":false,
    "net": false,
    "path": false,
    "stream": false,
    "tls": false,
    "crypto": false,
    "fs": false,
    "zlib": false
  }
```

The server starts with no issues then - but the browser window remains blank white with an error in the console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the 'web-request' module is not written to work in the browser rather on the node server. You need to use a different package for what you need to achieve.

Comment: In fact you shouldn't need any package at all because browsers nowadays natively support [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Yes, and in angular, you can use HttpClient for that.