# Text file create and upload in node server with Angular 6

Tags: node.js, file-upload, angular6, text-files

I am new to angular 6 and Node as well. Basically I have a requirement of creating a text file on button click and saving it to server using Node. Te save file will be in .txt format so that I could read from it again. I was trying using ng2-file-upload, but that is helpful for upload and save. Not getting any clue how to proceed!
I got the reference of File System API. How to use it from my Angular 6 Code?
Thanks in advance for help!!

Comment: You are missing the part where you explain where the text in the text file is coming from. I assume it's some sort of text box on the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. As per my requirement, I need to create a .txt file on a form submission with the form input contents.

Comment: I tried to use the below code 

`const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {

    if(err) {

        return console.log(err);

    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
}); `

I am getting error "Module not found" 

As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202948/update-to-angular-v6-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs, the node modules can't be accessed from Angular6. any alternatives?

Comment: It looks like you'll have to use an external library to get it done: http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/ for example.