# TypeError: window.require is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Im trying to build an electron app and want to use window.require. Unfortunately the compiler says "TypeError: window.require is not a function". Ironically **require** works **only** in main.js.

Here the code Im trying to run:

```
const electron = window.require('electron')
const low =  window.require('lowdb')
const FileSync = window.require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
```

I read in another post that somebody have had the same problem and it was fixed by adding this code into the .html file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Gehaltseinstellungen_Hinzufügen.js">
        window.nodeRequire = require;
        delete window.require;
        delete window.exports;
        delete window.module;
    </script>
```

Also the author said using "nodeRequire" instead of require would solve the problem but it doesn't...

Another option I read about is that the NodeIntegration is set to false while the rendering process is activated, but I don't know how to activate Node while rendering.

Comment: I'd lke to add that I had the same issue all of a sudden and couldn't figure out what was going on. Turns out I had an iframe with another iframe as the value of its `src` attribute. Although I don't think this particular detail is very relevant, it shows that **the `window.require()` itself wasn't the problem**. I hope this helps some others who are dealing with the issue.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is unclear what version of `Electron` you are using. The syntax you are using is non-standard.

First – if you are using `Electron` 5.0, [nodeIntegration is false by default](https://electronjs.org/blog/electron-5-0#security-improvements) in `BrowserWindows` so you need to specify it explicitly when you create your window:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
})
```

---

Given the above, the syntax below works fine (i.e. no 'window' reference needed):

```
const { ipcRenderer, remote } = require('electron');
```

Comment: upvoted because `webPreferences` object helped me get rid of the error but I still needed to prefix `window`

Comment: @BlueBot indeed, `require('electron')` not working but `window.require('electron')` is fine

Comment: love you man, i mean really why does they not highlight this !
thank you

Comment: This was the missing ingredient for my project to work. Thank you!

Comment: works above solution with `window.require('electron')` but simple `require(electron)` caused another issue

Comment: @Ganesh - not seeing that here. Maybe our project structures  or some other setup params are different (though I do not understand why that would matter)

Comment: `nodeIntegration: true` is a security risk https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#isolation-for-untrusted-content

Comment: @JuanSolano – not necessarily. I have an Electron app which does not connect to the internet. There is no security risk there, nor with remote content which is trusted.

Comment: My source code looks like yours but the error above still appears

Comment: window.require ==> can be needed for usage with webpack

Answer (score 60):

you can set the **webPreferences.contextIsolation** to be **false** like this

```
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false
    }
```

it maybe works

Comment: contextIsolation to false fixed it for me (I already had nodeIntegration true). When I updated electron apparently its true by default: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation

Comment: This solution fixed the issue for me

Comment: `contextIsolation` became `true` by default in Electron 12, so this fixed it for me as well: https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v12.0.0

Comment: @JohnnyOshika It is the root reason ! thank you.

Comment: thank you masaikk . This  resolve my  window.requie('electro') issue.

Answer (score 26):

Needed all 3 setup like so to make this work:

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true,
  enableRemoteModule: true,
  contextIsolation: false,
},
```

> note: macbook m1, big sur 11.4, maybe it has to do something about OS, idk.

P.s. As mentioned in comments, before using `nodeIntegration` - check the Electron docs to understand when it may be a security issue:

> Isolation For Untrusted Content A security issue exists whenever you
> receive code from an untrusted source (e.g. a remote server) and
> execute it locally. As an example, consider a remote website being
> displayed inside a default BrowserWindow. If an attacker somehow
> manages to change said content (either by attacking the source
> directly, or by sitting between your app and the actual destination),
> they will be able to execute native code on the user's machine.
>
> ⚠️ Under no circumstances should you load and execute remote code with
> Node.js integration enabled. Instead, use only local files (packaged
> together with your application) to execute Node.js code. To display
> remote content, use the  tag or BrowserView, make sure to
> disable the nodeIntegration and enable contextIsolation.

Source: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#isolation-for-untrusted-content

Comment: I know they say not to comment to say thank you, But I just spent the past 4 hours looking on how to fix this issue, and this right here was the solve! Thank You!

Comment: @PandaDev we all been there  Glad it helped

Comment: `nodeIntegration: true` is a security risk https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#isolation-for-untrusted-content

Comment: @JuanSolano if your context is untrusted, yes it may be.

Comment: @PandaDev, who is saying not to say 'thank you'? Because of thank yous I we see it's working for somebody

Comment: @cikatomo It was in the comment guidelines for stack applications, it had an example displaying refrain from thanks in the comments

Comment: @cikatomo on Stackoverflow "Thank you" is upvote. If you found question, answer, or comment useful you should upvote. You can read more at help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 7):

I also met this issue in Electron + Angular.

```
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    contextIsolation: false
  }
```

Configuration above works for me.

Comment: Repeated solution

Comment: `nodeIntegration: true` is a security risk https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#isolation-for-untrusted-content

Comment: @JuanSolano if your context is untrusted, yes it may be.

Answer (score 5):

Same issue in Electron + React + Typescript. This solved it for me

```
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    enableRemoteModule: true,
    contextIsolation: false
}
```

Comment: `nodeIntegration: true` is a security risk https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#isolation-for-untrusted-content

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with this problem for a couple of days.
Could not figure out for the life of me.
Went through a lot of docs and stackoverflow and finally!!!!

I fixed this error the following way :

create a file preload.js :

```
    const { remote } = require('electron');
    window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

then in main.js/electron.js:

```
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      //this line is crucial
      preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), '/path-to-file/preload.js'),
      contextIsolation: false
    }
  })
```

and finally in App.js:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = window
```

I got ipcRenderer in window from electron.
I'm pretty sure you can  get anything else that you would want.

Comment: Mine was fixed with this (electron+React[js])

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify web preferences as has been suggested, and I would recommend not doing it unless you have a better reason to because of the implied security issues (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#isolation-for-untrusted-content).

Instead, what you can do is use the preload script to add any functionality you need to `window`. Like this for example:

preload.js (located in the root folder):

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', {
  invoke: (event) => ipcRenderer.invoke(event),
});
```

webPreferences in main.js:

```
webPreferences: {
  preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
}
```

Now in your code you can reference it:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = window as any;
const response = await ipcRenderer.invoke(...);
```

Reference documentation here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload#communicating-between-processes