# fs.readdirSync is not a function - electron + react.js

Tags: reactjs, electron, fs

I'm trying to write a *electron* app with *React.js* and this app accesses file system.

Here is my `fileWalker.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function *walkFolders (folder, recurseLevel = 0) {
  try {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(folder);

    for (const file of files) {
      try {
        const pathToFile = path.join(folder, file);
        const stat = fs.statSync(pathToFile);
        const isDirectory = stat.isDirectory();
        if (isDirectory && recurseLevel > 0) {
          yield * walkFolders(pathToFile, recurseLevel - 1)
        }
        else {
          yield {
            rootDir: folder,
            fileName: file,
            isDir: isDirectory,
            stat: stat
          }
        }
      }
      catch (err) {
        yield {
          rootDir: folder,
          fileName: file,
          error: err
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    yield {
      rootDir: folder,
      error: err
    }
  }
}

export default walkFolders;
```

Then in my `App.js`, I wrote:

```
  getFolders(absolutePath) {
    let folders = [];
    // check incoming arg
    if (!absolutePath || typeof absolutePath !== 'string') {
      return folders
    }
    for (const fileInfo of walkFolders(absolutePath, false)) {
      // all files and folders
      console.log(fileInfo);
      if ('error' in fileInfo) {
        console.error(`Error: ${fileInfo.rootDir} - ${fileInfo.error}`);
        continue
      }
      // we only want folders
      if (!fileInfo.isDir) {
        continue
      }
      const node = this.createNode(fileInfo)
      folders.push(node)
    }
    return folders
  }

   ...
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFolders("E:/gits");
  }
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.getFolders=this.getFolders.bind(this);
    ...
  }
...
```

But I get this error:

**`TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function`**

[image]

**How can I resolve this?**

Comment: Create a new file, write two lines, `const fs = require('fs'); const files = fs.readdirSync('/');` Run it, see what happens?

Comment: @JimJin nothing happened..

Comment: Then, it means that `fs.readdirSync()` works fine. If you want to find out the culprit in your original project, I recommend you a method similar to binary search. You can comment out half of your code, see whether the error remains. If yes, continue commenting the half of the reminding. If no, use the same way to find it in the commented half.

Comment: @JimJin , when i put those same line inside react code, i got error, see : https://i.stack.imgur.com/diT2e.png

Answer (score 2):

It seems Webpack config error. The default value of [`target`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) in webpack is 'web'. In electron js, it should be `electron-renderer`.

If you are created a react app by using create-react-app, Then you have to eject the webpack configurations and update the configurations.

Or, If you are not positioned to eject the webpack means, there are some options are there.

By using [`react-app-rewired`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) we can override the webpack configurations.

1) Install react-app-rewired

For create-react-app 2.x with Webpack 4:

```
$ npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev
```

For create-react-app 1.x or react-scripts-ts with Webpack 3:

```
$ npm install react-app-rewired@1.6.2 --save-dev
```

2) Create a **config-overrides.js** file in the root directory

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.target = 'electron-renderer';
  return config;
}
```

3) 'Flip' the existing calls to react-scripts in npm scripts for start, build and test

```
/* package.json */

  "scripts": {
-   "start": "react-scripts start",
+   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
-   "build": "react-scripts build",
+   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
-   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
+   "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Then start the server. It might be work. :-)

Comment: it may have solved the old error, but now it gives new error , like this :https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2sRF.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56095485/8579855 - This answer may help you

Comment: This solution has way fewer upvotes than it should