# TypeError window.require is not a function - Angular Test with Electron

Tags: angular, electron, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular project run with Electron. My code compiles and works nicely, and now I've come to test it. Before I even start writing tests, all the `'shouldCreate'` tests are failing with the message `"TypeError: window.require is not a function"`.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56091343/typeerror-window-require-is-not-a-function/56095485) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265958/electronjs-window-require-not-a-function), as well as a few others on the matter, but none of them address what to do if it only fails in tests.

How can I get my tests to succeed, even with my code having things like `window.require('fs')` and the like? Again, the code compiles and runs (at least in the dev environment) but my tests fail before I have written them

TIA

EDIT: My code is based off of [this github project](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like those errors appeared because I opened the browser to the port where karma was running, and as a result, those errors appeared. (Chrome really does not have access to the window etc, so it makes sense.)

When I ran the tests from the CMD w/o opening the browser, everything succeeded and all's well that ends well