# Migrate Angular 8 to Angular 9

Tags: angular, migrate, angular9

After ng serve i have an errors in the console. How i can fix it?

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'project-path\node_modules\resolve\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'project-path\node_modules\resolve\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tslint/lib/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'project-path\node_modules\tslint\lib'
```

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: Also, have you tried deleting the entire `node_modules` and then reinstalling those by `npm i`?

Comment: This solved my issue
=>Uninstall node_modules with command "npm uninstall"
=>Delete node_modules folder
=>Delete package-lock.json 
=>Install node_modules with "npm install"

Answer (score 2):

#### If you are using Angular Universal

You have to provide 2 different version of the file that uses `fs` in your code, as 2 service providers, one in the server module with fs, and the other without it.

If this doesn't make much sense, check the solution details here:
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/754#issuecomment-353616515

It appears this issue is not Angular 9 specific. See examples of the problem and solutions  from earlier versions of Angular here: [Update to Angular v6 - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202948/update-to-angular-v6-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs)

#### If you are not using Angular Universal

It could be a problem with one of your dependencies. In this case you can try telling Webpack (which Angular uses under the hood) to ignore `fs` in browser environment (non Node).

An example of this problem and the specifics of the solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52367183/146656

Comment: I don't use Universal. I tried this case https://stackoverflow.com/a/52367183/146656, but not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

1st : step you have to take a proper backup and follow the below steps

```
remove node_modules
remove package-lock.json
npm cache clean -f
```

(Optional)If you are already done with above please restart your machine. and start node and angular again.

2nd : adding the following to karma.conf.js

```
webpack: { node: { fs: 'empty', } }
```

Comment: I do not have karma.conf.js (I use JEST)

Comment: after completing the first step, nothing has changed