# Angular universal doesn't resolve .json files

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-universal

I build Angular Universal (SSR) application. Now I installed package for express server. Inside that package there are lines like that:

`require(./package)` -> this doesn't work (angular can't resolve it) because angular expects to require it like `require(./package.json)`

`require(../folderdir)` -> this doesn't work (angular can't resolve it) because angular expects to require it like `require(../folderdir/index.json)`

How can I tell angular universal to also resolve `.json` extensions?

P.S. I use angular cli and I don't have webpack config file to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Step:1-Update your package.json so that you can use fs module on client side browser [npm-package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#browser)

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  }
```

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50202948/5695162)

Use fs module to read `.json file`

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
 import {TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
          
  declare var require: any;
  import {join} from 'path';
      
  const fs = require('fs');
      
  export class Loader {
      
    getJson(){

   const assets_folder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist', 'server', this.prefix);
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${assets_folder}/${lang}${this.suffix}`, 'utf8'));

  return jsonData;
 }
}
```

[**More Information on importing json with SSR**](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/754)

or you can import entire json file directly

```
import * as indexJSON from 'assets/index.json';


use indexJSON where ever you want.
```

or

add file `typings.d.ts` to the project's root folder with below content

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

and then import your data like this:

`import * as data from './example.json';`

### update July 2019:

Typescript 2.9 ([docs][2]) introduced a better, smarter solution. Steps:

1. Add `resolveJsonModule` support with this line in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
```

the import statement can now assumes a default export:

`import data from './example.json';`
[**Credit**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991237/how-to-import-json-file-into-a-typescript-file)

Comment: I am not one who imports, it's written in node package, I can't change it

Comment: Perhaps you can fork it make the changes and use it

Comment: or use an alternate lib