# Angular ,extract-zip , typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, compression, unzip

I need help.I am trying to decompress a zip file with angular using extract-zip.

but I got the following error :

./node_modules/extract-zip/index.js:9:4-17 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\TONWEYA\ig-recovery\node_modules\extract-zip
'

./node_modules/fd-slicer/index.js:1:9-22 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\TONWEYA\ig-recovery\node_modules\fd-slicer'

./node_modules/yauzl/index.js:1:9-22 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\TONWEYA\ig-recovery\node_modules\yauzl'

./node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js:1:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in 'D:\TONWEYA\ig-recovery\node_modules\zl
ib\lib'

this is my code :

```
import extractZip from 'extract-zip';


async onFileSelected(event: any): Promise<void> {
   this.fichier = event.target.files[0];

   extractZip("D:\\TONWEYA\\unzip\\demo.zip", {dir: "D:\\TONWEYA\\unzip"});

 }
```

I am really wait for your help. I'm using angular 13.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the fact that `extract-zip` package uses node native imports, see [this issue](https://github.com/maxogden/extract-zip/issues/41).

In order to fix it you need to extend your app's configuration, so you can use them in browser.
Take a look at the solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087330/angular-6-many-cant-resolve-errors-crypto-fs-http-https-net-path-stream/52367183#52367183)

In your case your config should look like:

```
"browser": {
    ...,
    "fs": false
}
```

**Update:**
Also take a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202948/update-to-angular-v6-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs/63427821#63427821), you may notice other possible solutions for your case.
Another option is to use a different library like [jszip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip). This library does not use native imports.

Comment: I tried all of these things. but it doesn't work. please , if you have a code that work, send it to me. Im using angular 13.