# How to check if a directory exists and is not empty?

Tags: typescript, jszip

```
zip.loadAsync(files).then(function(directory:any){
if (directory.folder("Mary")){ // not sure what to do here
      console.log("fail");
    }
else{
directory.folder("Mary").forEach(function (filename: any) {Console.log(filename);});
    };
}
```

I try to check if the directory "Mary" does exist and is not null before I do something to every file inside "Mary". But I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can import fs and use this

```
import * as fs from "fs";

fs.readdir("Mary", function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
       // some sort of error
    } else {
       if (!files.length) {
           // directory appears to be empty
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function isNotEmptyDir(dirpath){
if(fs.lstatSync(dirpath).isDirectory()){
    const filepaths = fs.readdirSync(dirpath)
    console.log('filepaths :' + filepaths)
    if(filepaths.length > 0){
        return true
    }
}
return false
```

}

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: fs is a nodejs library and it cannot be used by Angular applications. Once the code compiles it will throw an error stating that it cannot resolve the fs module, doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63427821/9333976) does not help either. So, I believe this has to be solved on a different layer rather than the front-end.