# ng serve can't resolve imports from src path, but work when using relative path

Tags: angular

when importing something using src\app... angular cli gives error 
" Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/app/shared/k/k-api.service' in 'C:...' ".
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/k/k-api.service'

```
import { KAPIService } from 'src/app/shared/k/k-api.service';
```

but when using relative path it works just fine

```
import { KAPIService } from '../../../../shared/k/k-api.service';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve it by changing 
`"baseUrl": "./",` to `"baseUrl": "./src"`, in tsconfig.json
then

```
import { KAPIService } from 'app/shared/k/k-api.service';
```

not sure if this is the best solution, but works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the path 'src/some/path/here' cannot be resolved by the webpack. It is not exactly an `absolute path` as you might think.

You could try editing the webpack config and adding an `alias` [refer here : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/ ]

and adding say something like `'Src' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')` so that you can use it as an absolute base `Src`

Comment: it's not strait forward to edit webpack in angular newer versions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187556/angular-cli-where-is-webpack-config-js-file-new-angular6-does-not-support-ng-e

Answer (score 0):

Check the moduleResolution property in reconfigure.json. when set to `node` and given path is not relative, the module is resolved from the `node_modules` directory from where the webpack is started . If the module is not found, the node module in parent directory is searched (recursive search until the root is reached)

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this opening the **root project directory** (the parent of src) in VSCode and not the **src** directory.