# Remove "App Ready" status bar in Angular dev server

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server, angular-cli-v8

I used the Angular CLI to create a new project and am seeing a status bar at the top of my app that says "App Ready".  I can't find anything about this header bar in the Angular CLI docs, and it can be pretty distracting during development.  How do I get rid of it?

```
$ ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.23
Node: 12.14.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.23
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.23
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.23
@angular/cli                      8.3.23
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.23
@schematics/angular               8.3.23
@schematics/update                0.803.23
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your `src/index.html` and `src/app/app.component.html` to see if the status bar might be hiding in there? I haven't seen this before, and have started a lot of Angular Projects from the CLI.

Comment: Yes, just checked both of those files and don't see anything related to this.  I just added the output of `ng version` to my question.

Comment: Can you show what you see if you inspect the "App ready" bar? It might give hints of where to look.

Comment: Hi - frustrating I know but you are doing nothing wrong and it is easy to solve without inspecting the rendered page :) see my answer below. All the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'problem' is that your page is loading within the Dev Server iframe. As explained in the Webpack documentation, [it can be specified that it should be loaded inline](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/webpack-dev-server#inline-mode). This config can be [saved in a JS file in the root of Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53910947/1667410) (now without needing to use `ng eject`).

That said, **the simplest solution** is to just go to the url outwith the iFrame directly i.e. change the URL in the browser location bar from:

`http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/`

to a path relevant to your project e.g.:

`http://localhost:4200/index.html`

Which, if using the router, will redirect to the base route - so you can just access any route without the status bar e.g.:

`http://localhost:4200/home`

Comment: Wow.  Maybe the Angular CLI team should consider replacing the default "Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/" message in the console with the base URL, sans webpack-dev-server.  Thanks!