# MapBox GL JS v2 with Angular 14: WebWorker error - Babel transpilation

Tags: angular, webpack, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've installed MapBox GL JS v2 in an Angular 14 project. The app loads but the map is empty/grey. The following error is shown in the console:

> error occurred while parsing the WebWorker bundle. This is most
> likely due to improper transpilation by Babel; please see
> https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/install/#transpiling

The link to the official documentation contains various solutions to try. The first solution is to include the following:

```
import mapboxgl from '!mapbox-gl';
```

However, VS Code doesn't like the exclamation mark and gives the error:

> Cannot find module '!mapbox-gl' or its corresponding type declarations

The other solutions suggest editing *webpack.config.js* but this doesn't seem straightforward for an Angular project given the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187556/angular-cli-where-is-webpack-config-js-file-new-angular6-does-not-support-ng-e).

Is there something more simple that I am missing?

Comment: Is IE in your .browserlistrc file? That will cause ES5 transpilation.