# sqlite3 on Angular project causes many "Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in [...]" and "BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used [...]"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, sqlite

**Note 1**: on a regular Node application the sqlite3 module works as intended.

**Note 2:** I don't want to access the database from the browser, it is to be at the back-end.

**Note 3**: yes, I'm new to Node and Angular.

Trying to use [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3) on an Angular project causes a lot of compiler errors like the ones below.

```
node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js:54:13-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '[...]\node_modules\tar\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


./node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:32:4-22 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'process' in '[...]\node_modules\tar\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "process": require.resolve("process/browser") }'
        - install 'process'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "process": false }
```

The list is huge, there is a lot messages like that.

## Version of everything

```
>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 16.2.5
Node: 20.6.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.8.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.2.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.5
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.5
@angular/cli                    16.2.5
@schematics/angular             16.2.5
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
zone.js                         0.13.3
```

## Description

The **tl;dr**: create an Angular project, install the sqlite3 module, use it.

To reproduce the problem, fist create a new Angular project as in [Setting up the local environment and workspace](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local). In short (accept the defaults):

```
ng new my-app
cd my-app
ng serve --open
```

Everything works fine. So, [install](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3#installing) node-sqlite3 running `npm install sqlite3`.

Create the file `src/db.ts` containing the lines bellow:

```ts
import * as sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';
const db = new sqlite3.Database('file.db');

export function test(): void {
    db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        text TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
        )
        STRICT;`
    );

    db.run('INSERT INTO Test VALUES (NULL, ?)', 'Hello, world');
    db.each('SELECT * FROM Test', (err, row) => {
        console.log('Test data', row);
    });
}
```

Use this function anywhere in the file `app.component.ts`. I did it inside the constructor for simplicity.

```ts
import { test } from 'src/bd';
//...
constructor() {
    test();
}
```

Run `ng serve --open` again and watch the command prompt be spammed with error messages.

As per posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187556/angular-cli-where-is-webpack-config-js-file-new-angular6-does-not-support-ng-e) one, there is no more `webpack.config.js` when using Angular, where fallbacks used to be configured. I tried custom builder following [Aniket Thakur's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53910947/19395835), but got only partial success (and the introduction of other issues...).

In my actual project I tried `ng generate service` hoping putting the data access code in a service would cause Angular to use the module with no issue. It didn't.

## The question

So, how can I use SQLite in my back-end while using Angular for front-end? I really, really, really don't want to use yet another lib in my project. That said, how do I configure sqlite3 or Angular to make it possible?